# Where to place delete operator for dynamic variable

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, delete-operator

I am trying to figure out where to place the `delete pointer`statement in the program below. I want to clear the memory space that `pointer` is pointing to in order to avoid memory leaks. It seems that no matter where I put it, I get an error stating:

```
main(8282,0x7fff95d823c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff582d3960: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I am not sure how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    //initialize vector
    vector<int> historyValues;

    //initialize pointer and int variable
    int *pointer;
    pointer = new int;
    pointer = 0;
    int currentValue;

    //make pointer point to the address of currentValue
    pointer = &currentValue;

    //increment pointer by 1 for a total of 10 times.
    //since pointer is pointing at currentValue, currentValue should change also.
    //push back the current value of currentValue into the vector.

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        *pointer += 1;
        historyValues.push_back(currentValue);
    }

    //print final results
    cout << "currentValue: " << currentValue << endl;
    cout << "*pointer: " << *pointer << endl;

    cout << "History of integers stored in currentValue: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < historyValues.size(); i++) {

        cout << historyValues[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Program finished" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that C++ has no such thing as a dynamic variable.

Answer (score 3):

The only place in this program where `pointer` refers to a dynamic memory block that can be freed is between `pointer = new int;` and `pointer = 0;`  If you move the `delete pointer` between those two lines, you'll be fine.

The result of the change is then:

```
pointer = new int;
delete pointer;
pointer = 0;
```

However, you might as well just remove all three of those lines and start with `pointer = &currentValue;` because your code never uses the dynamically allocated `int`.

---

Also, your comment "increment pointer" is incorrect.  You are incrementing the target of the pointer, not the pointer.

Comment: What I am trying to do with is increment `*pointer` in order to indirectly change the value of `currentValue` . If i get rid of  of  `pointer = new int;` and  `pointer = 0`, won't there still be a memory leak anyway?

Comment: @HernanRazo: If you take out `new int` there will be no leak.  Variables with automatic lifetime, such as `currentValue`, are automatically freed when the function returns.

Comment: @Hernan I suspect you misunderstand some things about pointers: 1) Pointer `p` holds an _address_ to where ***actual value*** is stored. 2) You can get/set the _address_ using `p` or the _value_ at the address using `*p`. 3) You _can_ dynamically allocate memory (e.g. with **new**) and set the address. 4) But that's ***not*** the only way to set the address (e.g. set `p=<address of existing variable>`). 5) Whenever you ***do*** allocate memory dynamically (new), you should release it _when appropriate_ (delete). 6) If you change the address before you delete, you can no longer delete; and leak

Comment: @CraigYoung: I didn't want to rewrite without first making sure I wasn't overlooking a valid problem.  Since you're saying it's just a matter of being potentially misunderstood, I'll now clarify that.